# Convert Magento theme to wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, magento, themes

I had a Magento theme downloaded and i want to use it to my wordpress site. I searched wordpress version of the theme but no luck. Is there a way i can convert magento theme to wordpress theme?

Comment: Themes include templates, the templates must be completely rewritten to "convert". Wordpress don't speak no Magento.

Comment: Ok thank you Fiasco for response. So there's no way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to do that, you will need to migrate your theme manually, with that I mean, you will need to code the theme in WordPress.

Comment: I'm hoping that there is. btw, i think i have to do it manually. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of magically rewriting a Magento theme into a Wordpress theme.

Like Enrique said, you will need to recode the entire thing.. well, almost, at least. This really depends on whether or not you simply want them to look the same or to actually be structured identically. The former is easier.

You can most likely salvage the majority of the skin folder, especially css and js. Then it's a matter of matching up Magento element names to corresponding Wordpress element names. An example might be `.button` and `.btn`.

As far as the structure, you may want to simply view source on the theme as it renders on the actual site, grab the source and do some heavy analysis. Figure out which portions render in the header, content and footer and try to piece them into the corresponding Wordpress files. It's a daunting task but believe it or not, I've done similar things before.

Note that Wordpress is nowhere near as complex in terms of application structure as Magento, so you'd really be dumbing down the Magento theme to accomplish this.

Comment: That was heartbreaking :). i think i have just go through copy the styling and behavior by hand.

Comment: Probably not as heartbreaking as the experience you'll have using WP as an e-commerce platform :)

Answer (score 0):

To convert your theme unfortunately you will have to manually rebuild it line by line for Wordpress. You said that you could not find the wordpress version of the theme but if possible the theme vendors might have HTML or PSD versions of the theme which would be a much closer starting point than Magento to Wordpress conversion.